# Python SendKeys Stopped working overnight

Tags: python, sendkeys

A little frustrated here, I was working on automating a task with Pyautogui and SendKeys, and it was working great last night, I come in this morning for work and it now only half works. The Script will copy the information I need it to, but it wont paste.

I'm utterly confused because the two lines of code are essentially the same, but one works and the other does not...

```
V = str("E" + str(i))
pyautogui.moveTo(384,728)
time.sleep(.5)
pyautogui.doubleClick()
SendKeys("""^c""")
time.sleep(.25)
wb = Workbook("C:\Users\jleonar\Documents\CDSCMacro.xls")
Sheet('frm resulting file').activate() 
time.sleep(.15)
excel.Range(V).Select()
time.sleep(.15)
SendKeys("""^v""")
```

This is a sample of the code that works for copying but not for pasting.. any ideas?

Cheers,

Justin